# Swift Reduce - Add Int Values of Strings

Tags: arrays, swift, nsarray

I have an array `ZZ` of custom object `A` with property:

```
String a1
```

I would like to add the `a1` property of all the elements in the array and return an NSNumber value. Since the value a1 is a string, I will also have to cast it into a double on the go too.

I tried to do something on the lines of:

```
ZZ?.reduce(0, {$0.Int(a1) + $1.Int(a1)})
```

but getting plenty of errors regarding the syntax.

How can I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this way.

If your string contain `Double` value:

```
let result = zz.reduce(0) { $0 + Double($1.a1) ?? 0.0 }
```

If your string contain `Int` value:

```
let result = zz.reduce(0) { $0 + Int($1.a1) ?? 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using `reduce` directly on the `zz` array, you could apply an attempted `Double` initialization (by the failable [`init?(_:String)` initializer of `Double`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/double/1538328-init)) of the `a1` member of each element of `zz` within a `flatMap` call on `zz`, whereafter you apply `reduce` to sum the elements which were successfully initialized as `Double` instances.

```
struct Custom {
  let a1: String
  init(_ a1: String) { self.a1 = a1 }
}

let zz: [Custom] = [Custom("1.4"), Custom("z"), Custom("3.1")]

let sumOfValids = zz.lazy.flatMap{ Double($0.a1) }.reduce(0, +) // 4.5
```

For the last part (if you really want this)

> *"I would like to add the a1 property of all the elements in the array
>   and **return an `NSNumber` value**"*.

you can simply make use of the [appropriate `NSNumber` by `Double` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumber/1407545-init).

Finally, note that none of the above performs attempted *casting* from `String` to `Double`, but attempted *initialization* of a `Double` by a `String` value, making use of the failable by `String` initializer blueprinted in [`LosslessStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/losslessstringconvertible), to which `Double` conforms.

> *"Since the value `a1` is a `String`, I will also have to cast it into a
>   `Double` on the go too"*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a non convertable String to Double means a 0.0 value...

```
public class Custom
{
    public var theProperty: String

    public init(value: String)
    {
        self.theProperty = value
    }
}

let c1: Custom = Custom(value: "1.1")
let c2: Custom = Custom(value: "a")
let c3: Custom = Custom(value: "3.2")

let array: [Custom] = [ c1, c2, c3 ]

let result: Double = array.map({
    guard let theProperty = Double($0.theProperty) else
    {
        return 0.0
    }

    return theProperty 

})
.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1 }

print(result)
```